# Add Year Index to a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am really new to Python but I need to use a already existing iPython notebook from my professor for analyzing a dataset (using python 2). The data I have is in a .txt document and is a list consisting of numbers with a "," as decimal seperator. I managed to import this list and plot it––all good till here.

My problem now is:
I want an **index** (year) on the x-axis of my chart starting at 563 for the first value going till 1995 for the last value (there are 1,433 data points in total). How can I add this index to the list without touching the original data?

Here is the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))

import os
D = open(os.path.expanduser("~/MY_FILE_DIRECTORY/Data.txt"))
Dat = D.read().replace(',','.')
Dat = [float(x) for x in Dat.split('\n')]
D.close()

plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.plot(Dat, 'b-')
cutmin = 0
cutmax = 1420
plt.axvline(cutmin, color = 'red')
plt.axvline(cutmax, color = 'red')
plt.grid()
```

Please help me! :-)

Comment: Try [plt.xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html).

Comment: Consider using: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim

Comment: `plot` usually takes two arguments, `plot(x,y)` You can supply a list of years or index or whatever you call it as `x` and the data as `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose when you say **index** you mean x-axis labels for your data which is different from the x-coordinates of your actual data (which you do not want to modify). You also say that these indices are years from 563 to 1995. `xticks()` function allows you to change the localtions and labels of the tick marks on your x-axis. So you can add these two lines to your code.

```
index = np.arange(563, 1996, 1, dtype=np.int32)
plt.xticks( index )
```

Hope this is what you wanted.